# Strong duality for a particular moment problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, duality-theorems, optimal-control

Reading the paper in this [Link (see pag 13)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05116.pdf) with the objective of understanding a topic related to stochastic optimization I came across a problem in demonstrating one of the theorems. The situation is the following:

**The context:** Let $(\Xi,\mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space where $\Xi\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $\widehat{\xi}_{i}\in \Xi$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$ and $\ell(\xi):=\max_{k\leq K}\ell_{k}(\xi)$ where $\ell_{k}:\Xi\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are functions. We denote by $\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ the set of probability distributions supported on $\Xi$. We consider the infinite optimizatión program
\begin{align} 
 &  \left\{\begin{array}{cl} {\displaystyle\sup_{\mathbb{Q}_{i}\in\mathcal{M}(\Xi)} }&{\displaystyle \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}\ell(\xi)\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi)} \\ \mbox{s.t.} & {\displaystyle \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}\left\|\xi-\widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\|\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi)\leq \varepsilon.} \end{array} \right.  \tag{P} 
\end{align}

We know that the dual problem is

\begin{align} 
 &  \left\{\begin{array}{cl} {\displaystyle\inf_{\lambda} }&{\displaystyle  \sup_{\mathbb{Q}_{i}\in\mathcal{M}(\Xi)}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}\ell(\xi)\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi) +\lambda \varepsilon -\lambda \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}\left\|\xi-\widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\|\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi) \right)} \\ \mbox{s.t.} & {\displaystyle \lambda \geq 0.} \end{array} \right.  \tag{D} 
\end{align}

We denote $\mathrm{Val(P)}$ and $\mathrm{Val(D)}$ the optimals values of $\mathrm{(P)}$ and $\mathrm{(D)}$ respectively.

**Assumption:** The paper I am reading establishes the following assumption:

> **Assumption 1.** ***[Convexity]***
>   The uncertainty set  $\Xi\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is convex and closed, and the negative constituent functions $-\ell_{k}$ are proper, convex and lower semicontinuous for all $k\leq K$. Moreover, se assume that $\ell_{k}$ is not identically $-\infty$ on $\Xi$ for all $k\leq K$.

**The problem:** If the convexity Assumption 1  holds, I need to show that we have strong duality, that is, I need to show that $\mathrm{Val(P)}=\mathrm{Val(D)}.$

**Remark:** According to the paper I am reading this is a consequence of a extended version of well-known strong duality result for moment problems, in this sense, the paper cite the following work:

> A. Shapiro, ***On duality theory of conic linear problems***, in Semi-Infinite Programming, M. A. Goberna and M. A. L´opez,
>   eds., Kluwer Academic Publishers, 2001, pp. 135–165

In this work, in Proposition 3.4, they show strong duality for the optimization problem
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cl} \max_{\mu\in\mathcal{C}} & \left\langle \varphi, \mu \right\rangle \\
\mbox{s.t.} & \mathcal{A}\mu-b \in K \end{array}   \right. \tag{1}
$$
where the context of $\mathrm{(1)}$ is the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Is (P) a particular case of (1)? If the answer is yes, then how can I make this evident?**